# Implementing generic jquery ajax functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webapp that has been refactored to use a single global variable in the formats

```
app.module.function
app.module.submodule.function
```

I want to refactor my existing generic

```
function getData(id, type, url, successHandler, rel) {

  var func = window[successHandler]

  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    data : {"search" : id, "type" : type, "rel" : rel},
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data) {
      if (func && typeof func === "function") {
        func(data, id, 0);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

function to take advantage of the success handlers being passed in.  For example, one such success handler is `clientRelationshipHandler`.

If the handler is defined as

```
function clientRelationshipHandler(results, id, type) { .. }
```

then `window["clientRelationshipHandler"]` returns a function.

However, if I change it to

```
app.module.submodule.clientRelationshipHandler = function(results, id, type { .. }
```

both

```
window["clientRelationshipHandler"]
window["app;.module.submodule.clientRelationshipHandler"]
```

return undefined and therefore break the generic `getData` functionality.  While using a function that is bound to a specific object, how can I implement a generic success handler for the Ajax query?

Comment: I would require the user to pass a function *reference* to `getData`, not a string. Then your function doesn't have to care where the callback is stored. Or even better, use promises: http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/.

Comment: +1. Whoever thought passing the function _names_ instead of the function themselves when callback is naturally expected, was _very_ wrong. Check `eval` if you really need this to work as it is, but really, you'd better not. )

Answer (score 2):

I would require the user to pass a function *reference* to `getData`, not a string:

```
function getData(id, type, url, successHandler, rel) { 
  $.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    data : {"search" : id, "type" : type, "rel" : rel},
    dataType: "json",
    success : function(data) {
      if (successHandler && typeof successHandler === "function") {
        successHandler(data, id, 0);
      }
    }
  });
}

// called as
getData(id, type, url, app.module.submodule.clientRelationshipHandler, rel);
```

Then your function doesn't have to care where the callback is stored, which makes it much more reusable (that's how callbacks are supposed to work).

If you want to preserve `this` inside the callback, either accept an additional parameter, `thisObj` and use `successHandler.call(thisObj, data, id, 0)` or let the user handle this himself (e.g. by using [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or providing an anonymous function).

---

An even better solution (IMO), would be to use [promises](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/):

```
function getData(id, type, url, rel) {
  return $.ajax({ // return the promise that `$.ajax` returns
    type : "POST",
    url : url,
    data : {"search" : id, "type" : type, "rel" : rel},
    dataType: "json"
  });
}
```

which is then called as

```
getData(id, type, url, rel).then(function(result) {
    app.module.submodule.clientRelationshipHandler(result, id, 0);
});
```

This completely decouples your code from the callback management and the calling code can handle the response in any way it wants to.